# nmtui "The device could not be readied for configuration"

Tags: networking, networkmanager, armbian

I'm trying to connect my armbian device to internet through ethernet. I use nmtui for that. ifconfig -a showes me that there is "eth0" interface. I changed it. I put static IPv4 address, gateway(got this from "ip r" on my computer and it is ip to the router interface page), DNS. I set "Auto connect" option. Now I try to activate it and it give me error:

```
Could not activate connection: Activation failed: Te device could not be readied for configuration
```

What can I do with that?

/etc/network/interfaces file contains(sorry, can't copy-paste from device):

```
# Wired adapter #1
allow-hotplug eth0
no-auto-down eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#iface eth0 inet static
#address 192.168.1.100
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.1.1
#dns-nameservices 192.168.0.1
```

This is not IP-address which I put in nmtoi settings and not this DNS.

nmcli dev output:

```
device type     state        connection
eth0   ethernet disconnected --
```

Comment: By any chance, is eth0 already defined in /etc/network/interfaces ? What is the output of `nmcli dev` ?

Comment: @Anonymous I edited queston with results.

Comment: I would suggest that you comment all references to eth0 in your interfaces files, since the device is to be managed by Network Manager. But what you can do first is check: `sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager.service` or with the -f option:  `sudo journalctl -ff -u NetworkManager.service` to follow output in real time while starting the interface. This could be a faulty configuration. You can also add the output of `mcli con show eth0` to your question

Comment: @Anonymous I commented all eth0  rows in "interfaces" and tried to activate connection through nmtui again and results is same.
In journalctl  at this moment wrote many rows like:

    `
    ...
    NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
    state change: prepare->config
    state change: config->failed(reason 'config-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed'
    ...
    `

What rows do you want from `nmcli con show eth0` ? I can't copy-paste results and it gives big-big text, but I can write some specific rows.

Comment: `nmcli con show eth0` will show the actual configuration for your interface, as it was generated by the nmtui tool. Perhaps an obvious mistake will stand out. It should not be that big, maybe over 100 lines but not huge. The output of journalctl can help too, look at the timestamps for the most recent entries. You can also use journalctl with the `--lines` options to fetch, say the 100 most recent lines. Instead of using nmtui to start the connection you can also use the command line eg: `nmcli con up eth0`. Perhaps you'll notice error messages although journalctl should be more complete.